# Spark Submitting my Job in a Jar

Tags: apache-spark, jobs

I'm going through the Apache Spark documentation and I'm learning that I could submit my jobs to the Spark cluster manager wrapped in a Jar using spark-submit.

My question is that let's say, I have a job that has many dependencies and the result of this could be that I have a jar file which is of the order of a couple of MB size.

How is this supposed to work? If I want to have to submit these jobs dynamically how can I do this?

Is there a valid use case to create these jobs as jar files dynamically at run time? Would I be doing this? Excuse me for my question as I'm completely new to using Apache Spark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am only working with standard-issue Spark so admittedly solutions referenced in the other answer related to IBM or other distributions may be closer to your needs.

As I am reading your question, you ask,

> "Is there a valid use case to create these jobs as jar files
>   dynamically at run time?"

Now I could hear you asking, "**should I run gradle build (or whichever build system) every time I call Spark?**"

Well that sounds crazy but indeed if you update your Java code and wish to run it with spark-submit (spark-submit script in $SPARK_HOME/bin), you need to shut down your slaves and master and restart them to read the new jar. ( But your name is SparkR so you have jars? :)

Now are you really asking, **is there a use case where every time you run Spark, you ship your jars around the whole cluster, even though they have not changed?** Basically the answer is you can, but if you have large jars it creates unnecessary network traffic. Depends on how much traffic / shuffling your actual job creates, relatively speaking.

But the best approach (IMHO) is to place your jars in a directory like /usr/local/spark/jars *on each node of the cluster* and (using spark-submit script in $SPARK_HOME/bin) use the --jars argument with a comma-delineated list of the jars.

I found that the --jars wants a comma-delineated list in an answer to another question, if I can find it again I'll link it here. I posed this question to document a broader answer (will link it later) to get all the options for submitting jars with --jars.

Per the docs:

When using spark-submit, the application jar along with any jars
included with the --jars option will be automatically transferred to
the cluster. Spark uses the following URL scheme to allow different

strategies for disseminating jars:

file: - Absolute paths and file:/ URIs are served by the driver’s HTTP file server, and every executor pulls the file from the driver HTTP server.

hdfs:, http:, https:, ftp: - these pull down files and JARs from the URI as expected

local: - a URI starting with local:/ is expected to exist as a local file on each worker node. This means that no network IO will be
incurred, and works well for large files/JARs that are pushed to each
worker, or shared via NFS, GlusterFS, etc.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

So there are a number of ways to do things, and Spark job jars can get quite large with all of the dependencies packaged in. Some people like the approach of things like the IBM Spark Kernel to be able to submit code that uses existing jars on a shared Spark context but that solution may not be for everyone.

Submitting jobs dynamically can also be done using a long running Spark Context with the Spark Job Server, but you can also just submit your jobs dynamically with spark-submit.

Once a job is finished you don't need to worry about the jar file, it will get cleaned up (although if you do use one of the long running solutions like the job server or spark kernel the cleanup happens differently).

Comment: Sharing the Spark context is not what Spark is intended for! My understanding is that each spark node has its own Spark context or? Correct me if I'm wrong?

Comment: No, the SparkContext only exists on the driver program. The workers all have their own executors.

Comment: Agreed with @Holden's comment, yet in the future multiple SparkContexts in one JVM are imagined, FWIW: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2243